# apache storm yaml blockmappingstart message

Tags: ubuntu, yaml, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I am trying to set up a storm cluster and I followed a tutorial on youtube . Everything was going ok but now that I am trying to run storm nimbus on terminal I have the following message:

> ....
>      Caused by: expected '', but found BlockMappingStart in 'reader', line 23, column 2:
>        storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
>        ^
>      ....

the `storm.yaml` file is the following:

```
########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration
# storm.zookeeper.servers:
  - "x.x.x.5"
#     - "server1"

storm.zookeeper.port: 2181

nimbus.host: x.x.x.5

nimbus.thrift.port: 6627

ui.port: 8772

storm.local.dir: "/usr/local/apacche-storm-0.10.0/data"

java.library.path: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/"

supervisor.slots.ports:

    - 6700
    - 6701
    - 6702
    - 6703
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is right at the beginning:

```
########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration
# storm.zookeeper.servers:
  - "x.x.x.5"
#     - "server1"

storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
```

Disregarding the commented lines, you have a sequence that's indented two spaces (`- "x.x.x.5"`) followed by a mapping that's not indented at all (`storm.zookeeper.port: 2181`). That's not valid. If you uncomment the second line, you also need to uncomment the second line (`storm.zookeeper.servers:`):

```
########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration
storm.zookeeper.servers:
  - "x.x.x.5"
  - "server1"

storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
```

Comment: that solved the problem but now when I type storm nimbus on terminal I have the following errors: 
<br/>ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in appenders.
<br/>ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in appenders.
<br/>ERROR Unable to locate appender ACCESS for logger backtype.storm.security.auth.authorizer
<br/>ERROR Unable to locate appender A1 for logger 
<br/>ERROR Unable to locate appender METRICS for logger backtype.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer

Comment: I don't have any Storm expertise so I can't help you, and anyway this isn't the appropriate place since this is a different problem. I recommend posting a new question.